# How to connect a flask API with google vision API?

Tags: python, flask, google-vision

Well I'm creating a android application which uses web services as well. For that I'm planing to create a web API using flask framework to communicate with my android application. I want my API to communicate with Google Vision API to analyze text from images which will be send from the android app. How can I make both two APIs to communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you haven't specified what your application does, or how it will work, I can only go on the assumption that you want to use your flask API as a middleman with the vision API.

You can use the Python [Vision API Client](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) within your flask api. The resulting data flow should look something like this:

```
Client
       >> Flask API
                    >> Vision API
                    << Vision API response
          Analyse response
       << Return response
Uses data
```